# IntelliJ IDEA error: not able to create a new project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am having trouble creating a new Java program. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1, and when I right click and select new, it only allows me to make a "File", which does not allow me to code.
[image: This is a snapshot of what it looks like:]

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Where, exactly, are you right-clicking?

Comment: @azurefrog 
I really basically right clicked everywhere. >.< I mainly tried rightclicking in the place on the left. If you open "1: Project", a sliding window will show from the left side of the screen showing which files are open, source files, etc. I mainly rightclicked in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a mistake. What you have to do, is go to file at the top left corner, and click Open. Make sure you go to the Java file, not the src file/anything else. It should work from then.